# Suppose $|a+b| = 2$, $|a|=2$, $|b|=1$, find $|a\cdot b|$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I know $$|a\cdot b| = |a||b|\cos(x)$$

But I don't know how to use this formula to calculate $|a\cdot b|$ given $|a+b|$.

Comment: Where do $a$ and $b$ live?

Comment: Are the answers given below consistent with each other?

Comment: No, but the first states "assuming that $a,b\in\mathbb R", the second says "for vectors a and b".

Answer (score 5):

We have that for vectors $a$ and $b$

$$|a+b|^2=(a+b)\cdot (a+b)=|a|^2+|b|^2+2(a\cdot b)$$